# Isn't it possible to compile knitr document from nested child?

Tags: nested, knitr, subdocument

I tried to make 2 stage nested child where I referred the main document as the first stage child. If I compile it from the first stage child, it works fine however when I tried to compile from the second stage child it stopped. I think their should be some indication in the second stage child for its main-main document in base stage.

The file structure is like,

```
Main.Rnw
   - FirstStage.Rnw
      - SecondStage.Rnw
```

At the top of `FirstStage.Rnw`, I wrote: `% !Rnw root = path/to/Main.Rnw`

At the top of `SecondStage.Rnw`, I wrote: `% !Rnw root = path/to/FirstStage.Rnw`

Comment: Am I in wrong place to ask question or is the question very irrelevant or foolish. Although there is no answers, there must be some comments. Hope to get one.